# Bison shift/reduce conflict in simple call expression/lambda grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, jison, shift-reduce-conflict

I've got a shift/reduce conflict that I can't figure out why it's occurring, and how to resolve it.

Given this grammar:

```
%token IDENTIFIER
%start Expression

%%

CallExpression
  : Expression "(" ")"
  ;

Lambda
  : "(" ")" "=>" Expression
  ;

Expression
  : IDENTIFIER
  | CallExpression
  | Lambda
  ;
```

I want to be able to parse expressions like this (not exhaustive):

```
foo
foo()
() => foo
() => () => foo
() => foo()
```

But I receive a shift/reduce conflict here:

```
State 11

    1 CallExpression: Expression . "(" ")"
    2 Lambda: "(" ")" "=>" Expression .  [$end, "("]

    "("  shift, and go to state 8

    "("       [reduce using rule 2 (Lambda)]
    $default  reduce using rule 2 (Lambda)
```

I thought I understood when shift/reduces occur, but this one is escaping me so I need to get schooled.

I tried learning more about the precedence directives available, `left, right, precedence, nonassoc` but any use of them I try does not resolve the ambiguity and they also give me `warning: useless precedence and associativity` so I'm doing *something* wrong. Hoping the answer is obvious to others.

I initially thought this was related to the fact that Lambdas start with `()` and CallExpressions end with it, but changing these tokens to not conflict makes no difference.

/facepalm

Comment: Is `() => foo()` a Lambda containing a CallExpression, or a CallExpression containing a Lambda?  I *think* that's what's confusing it here.

Comment: @aschepler a ha! that makes total sense! It's supposed to be the former, but I hadn't even realized the later is grammatically possible. Great catch. Presumably the precedence directives could solve this, but I'm inexperienced with them. Any thoughts?

Comment: @aschepler I forgot to say thank you! Thank you! This was the issue, and I found the correct precedence to resolve. If you want to add this as an answer, I'd accept it.